# Error while connecting to Roomba using roomba_500 package

Tags: ros, groovy-turtlebot, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As soon as I run -->

```
rosrun roomba_500_series roomba560_node
```

it gets connected for a fraction of second and then displays the error message

```
Error: Could not retrieve sensor packets while connecting roomba with laptop.
```

Any setting that needs to be done for persistent connection ? Please suggest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57139/error-while-connecting-to-roomba-using-roomba_500-package/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-06**:
Please find the details below:

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. ROS groovy
3. Yes, dmesg is giving results as expected.
4. FTDI cable
5. Roomba 500 series. Roomba 560 node.
6. Yes, i am running roscore first and then rosrun.

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-06**:
Details below:

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-08**:
I have installed ROS fuerte and checked... It's giving same error --> Couldn't retrieve sensor packets. Please suggest what should be done in case we face with this error on ROS fuerte / electric. I have checked everything again like USB permissions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was issue with roomba 521 base's FTDI serial connection due to which it was getting disconnected as soon as it gets connected to roomba. I have tested on two other turtlebots that we  have got in lab and everything working fine. Thanks for the help. Can you please accept this and close this as well as other questions that i raised. @arkapravo

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1